# using xmlbase in the Cygwin version of awk

Tags: awk, cygwin

I would like to use the [xmlbase functions](http://gawkextlib.sourceforge.net/xml/gawk-xml.html#xmlsimple) to escape some string using the Cygwin version of gawk.  It doesn't look like it is installed, so how does one go about installing it?

Answer (score 0):

`gawk-xml` isn't distributed with Cygwin's `gawk`, so you'll need to download it from SourceForge, https://sourceforge.net/projects/gawkextlib/files/. You'll need to use the files in the `awklib/xml` directory.